# Dask DataFrame aggregate to median

Tags: python, dask

I am trying to aggregate a dask dataframe to set of metrics, including median, but it looks like that median is not supported. Any chance to aggregate and get median?

```
st_agg = df.groupby(['start station id', 'end station id']).agg({'usertype':'count', 'tripduration':'median'})

>>> ValueError: unknown aggregate median
```

Comment: You may be surprised to learn that the parallel computation of the median is quite challenging

Comment: I understand that, but there are a few relatively cheap approximations for that.

Comment: Dask.dataframe supports approximate quantiles.  I don't think that these are exposed through the groupby.agg interface.  You might [open an issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new) requesting the feature.

Comment: Thanks, will do!

Comment: @Philipp_Kats did you manage to solve this issue? Currently struggeling with it, so if you have a solution...

Comment: No, I didn't, but there is an example on approximate quantiles [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/_modules/dask/array/percentile.html)

Answer (score 0):

As of October 6, 2021 there is not yet an implementation of this in Dask. There is an open Feature Request [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/5986#issuecomment-881960838).

**Workaround for Specific Cases**

From that same issue, this code below works for specific use cases in which the data for each grouped column fits on exactly 1 partition:

```py
ddf = dask.datasets.timeseries()
ddf = ddf.set_index('id')

median_fun = dd.Aggregation(
    name="median",
    # this computes the median on each partition
    chunk=lambda s: s.median(),
    # this combines results across partitions; the input should just be a list of length 1
    agg=lambda s0: s0.sum(),
)

median_ddf = ddf.groupby("id")["x"].agg(median_fun)
```

**General Solution**

For larger datasets, you could construct a custom aggregation function that calculates the median (or the 50th percentile) using ``dd.groupby.Aggregation`. If you do this, consider submitting it as a PR to resolve the feature request listed above.

See docs here: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.groupby.Aggregation.html#dask-dataframe-groupby-aggregation

**Median vs 50th Percentile**

Note that for most practical purposes, the 50th percentile and the median are equivalent when working with large datasets: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048470/is-50th-percentile-equal-to-median